# Is there a way to combine count and select query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hello i have two database tables, for this example im using table **Article** and **Comment**.

Here is schema:[image]

Is there a way to count `Comments` based on `FK_Article` and then counted values add to standart `select` query on `Article` table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aggregation and `COUNT` should be sufficient:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Date, COUNT(c.ID) AS Comments
FROM Article A
LEFT JOIN Comment c
  ON A.id = c.FK_Article
GROUP BY A.ID, A.Date
ORDER BY A.ID;
```

Comment: Great, it works and looks easier, than i expected. Thank you very much :)